# What is geometry datatype?

Tags: mapinfo, spatial-database, geometry

What are the basic that one should know about geometry datatype? How is it computed ? Why do we need geometry data type?

Edit:
I wanted to know why there is a different datatype called geometry. Is geometry some basic data type plus location information or more! How to understand the data in this column?

[image: Geometry]

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895270.aspx)
    The planar spatial data type, geometry, is implemented as a common language runtime (CLR) data type in SQL Server. This type represents data in a Euclidean (flat) coordinate system.

Comment: How basic do you need - point x,y, line xy,xy polygon xy1,xy2,xy3,xy1

Comment: I think you need to explain more.  What are you trying to understand?

Comment: Are you refering to the difference between a "Geography" and a "Geometry" datatype as seen in MS SQL 2008?

Comment: @ASPMapper No I mean why geometry?How is it interpreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope This will help you
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/datatype-geometric.html